# Gentle reboot of batch server (Task Schedular)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, scheduled-task, windows-server-2003-r2, task-scheduler

We have 3 Batch servers running hundreds of scheduled task using the built-in task schedular in Windows (2003R2 and 2012R2)

How do i prepare our servers for a reboot, so i wont interrupting a running tasks?

What im hope exist, is in some way to stop it from starting any more tasks, and maby reboot when all complete, or after a time period, or just inform me so i can do the reboot.

How do others reboot these kind of servers without interrupting critical running tasks?

Comment: The answer is likely "we do not". Task scheduler is not a scheduler app for complex scenarios - so you basically use it outside the intended use case. Some enterprise scheduling app may be better here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Stop Task Scheduler service (to prevent new tasks from starting).
2. Wait for existing tasks to finish.
3. Reboot.
4. Profit ???

Comment: That worked perfectly on our 2003 server, but stopped some, but not all, jobs on the 2012R2 server.
Think that is as good as it gets and i will use that way from now on. Thanks.